# Does the Apache v2 license require attribution in projects using binary plugins falling under the license?

Tags: google-analytics, thrift

There are a number of questions regarding attribution in the various open source licenses and the consensus seems to be that attribution is required for binary distributions. Is this also the case if you go one step further and you are using an unmodified binary distribution in one of your projects?

For example, Google Analytic's [Unity plugin](https://github.com/googleanalytics/google-analytics-plugin-for-unity) is licensed under the Apache v2 license. Does this mean that every game that uses the plugin needs to include a copy of the Apache v2 license? I'm sure that Google would be willing to make an exception here in either case but I don't see this explicitly mentioned anywhere in the project (and I'm positive that I've seen many games using the plugin and not including attribution).

Another potential scenario is in the use of the Apache Thrift project. The binary libraries are licensed under Apache v2 and any code generated using Thrift depends on them. If you use a binary plugin that in turn uses Thrift then does your project need to include the Thrift attribution and license as well?

My guess would be that it's the same and that you do need to include attribution and the license. I'm only asking because it seems to go against the spirit of the license in these cases where the purpose is more to protect the code than to require attribution for anything using plugins. I'm curious to hear any thoughts from somebody who knows more about the subtleties.